# Accessiblity of $ in when condtion in dataweave?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mule-esb

I have one requirement where entire response structure will be varied based on the current element. but in dataweave $ is not accessible with when, but with function it is accessible. Could you please suggest am i missing some thing here?
   `[1,2,5] map $ when $ > 1 otherwise 2` throws error. but same used like the below way works.
       `%function r(a) a when a > 1 otherwise 2
        ---
        [1,2,5] map r($)`

Could you please help me to understand the behaviour.

Thanks

Sushma.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after posting the question!!

it works with braces.

```
[1,2,5] map ($ when $ >1 otherwise 2)
```

Thanks

Sushma